# Remove item from filter list as well as from original list

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am working on `UISearchBar` on `Swift 4.0`. I have `originalList[ModelItem]` and `filterList[ModelItem]`. While in searching lets say user wants to delete on filterList 5th position which is 10th item on actual originalList. It make sense to delete this item from both of the list right? Items have no id or similar type field.

What would be the basic steps for such both-way deletion? I was looking for a general idea of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the model is a class and the `filterList` is created directly from the `originalList` (no new objects created, but both lists reference the same objects), then you can use this code:

```
let itemToDelete = filterList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
if let index = originalList.index(where: { $0 === itemToDelete }) {
    originalList.remove(at: index)
}
print(originalList)
print(filterList)
```

`===` operator will test the equality of the instances, thus identifying the proper instance to be removed from `originalList`.

In case you are using `struct` as a model, you will have to implement `Equatable` with some heuristics that would be able to detect if two instances are equal or not even without having an explicit identifier and then use `==` to find the proper instance in `originalList` to be removed.

Another alternative might be implementing search with index method, that would use the same filtering algorithm as your current filter method, but would take one more parameter - index in the `filterList` (`filterIndex`) along with the filter text, and based on that would compute and return an index in the `originalList` that matches the provided pair of filter text and `filterIndex`.

Yet another alternative, which I would not recommend (I would call it a hack) - you can keep a dictionary of indexes from `originalList` to `filterList` which you can use to have explicit mapping between `originalList` and `filterList`. This would however require that you always update that dictionary whatever change is made to one of the lists - every search, every deletion or removal or insertion would require an update of the mapping dictionary. This seems way to complicated and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options.

- You can maintain a mapping between the original and the filtered items positions, so you can perform deletion on both lists.
- You can make your items identifiable, so you can search for the corresponding item in the original list and delete it. Note that all reference types can be tested for identity (`===`).
- You can work with a filtered "view" to the original list, and not with a filtered copy, so the deletion will be performed on the original list naturally.

I don't think we have a standard solution for the latter option, which makes this approach the most complicated.

When choosing either of the first two options be careful with the original list updates that can happen while you operate on the filtered copy.